# How does std::begin deduce a type for braced-init-list?

Tags: c++, c++11

The following code fails:

```
template <typename T>
void func(T& t)
{
}

int main()
{
    func({1, 2, 3});
}
```

But with `auto a = {1, 2, 3};` it works because the rules allow `auto` to deduce an `std::initializer_list`. How is `std::begin` written to allow `std::begin({1, 2, 3})` to work?

Comment: C++ ISO says :auto can deduce std::initializer_list, but template can't. std::begin has an overload std::initializer_list

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::begin({1, 2, 3})` works because `std::begin` has an [overload taking an `std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list/begin2).

Comment: What's interesting is that this overload is defined in the `<initializer_list>` header, whereas the others are defined in `<iterator>`. I guess so you can still iterate over initializer lists even in a freestanding implementation, or something like that... (I never did get an actual answer as to the reason)

Comment: While `std::begin({1, 2, 3})` compiles, there are serious lifetime issues with the returned iterator (it's invalidated at the end of the full expression), and there's no way to get an end iterator to the same `initializer_list`, so the usefulness is quite limited.